# Changing variable in loop [Julia]

Tags: julia

In Julia 1.0, I'm trying to implement a for loop along the lines of:

```
while t1 < 2*tmax
    tcol = rand()
    t1 = t0 + tcol

    t0 = t1
    println(t0)
end
```

However, I am getting errors that t1 and t0 are undefined. If I put a "global" in front of them, it works again. Is there a better way to handle this than by putting global variables all over my code?

Answer (score 3):

The reason of the problem is that you are running your code in global scope (probably in Julia REPL). In this case you will have to use `global` as is explained here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/.

The simplest thing I can recommend is to wrap your code in `let` block like this:

```
let t1=0.0, t0=0.0, tmax=2.0
    while t1 < 2*tmax
        tcol = rand()
        t1 = t0 + tcol

        t0 = t1
        println(t0)
    end
    t0, t1
end
```

This way `let` creates a local scope and if you run this block in global scope (e.g. in Julia REPL) all works OK. Note that I put `t0, t1` at the end to make the `let` block return a tuple containing values of `t0` and `t1`

You could also wrap your code inside a function:

```
function myfun(t1, t0, tmax)
    while t1 < 2*tmax
        tcol = rand()
        t1 = t0 + tcol

        t0 = t1
        println(t0)
    end
    t0, t1
end
```

and then call `myfun` with appropriate parameters to get the same result.