# Editing a value inside a for loop

Tags: julia, control-flow

In Julia, I'm very surprised the following does not work:

```
# Make a random value
val = rand()
# Edit it *inside an if statement in a for loop*
for i in 1:10
    println("current value of val = ", val)
    if true
        val = val * 2. 
    end
end
```

Trying to run this leads to:

```
UndefVarError: val not defined
```

The issue appears to be the `if` statement. For example, this runs fine (other than not editing `val`!):

```
val = rand()
for i in 1:10
    println("current value of val = ", val)
#    if true
#        val = val * 2. 
#    end
end
```

Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing variable in loop \[Julia\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51909814/changing-variable-in-loop-julia)

Comment: When creating a random scalar, you should write `val()` instead of `val(1)[1]`, which is an unnecessary and (10x as) slow detour.

Comment: @DNF: I think you mean `rand()`, not `val()`. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that you'll typically only encounter this behaviour when working explicitly in the REPL (i.e. in global scope). For example, I don't think it can ever arise in IJulia, since everything is in a local scope. A really easy work-around is to just put all your code in a `let ; #code here ; end` block, since this moves everything into local scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Julia version 1.x, you need to use the ***global*** keyword, when updating a global variable inside a loop, because it creates a new ***local*** scope:

```
julia> val = rand()
0.23420933324154358

julia> for i in 1:10
         println("Current value of val = $val")
         if true
           val = val * 2
         end
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: val not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at ./REPL[2]:2 [inlined]
 [2] top-level scope at ./none:0

julia> for i in 1:10
         println("Current value of val = $val")
         if true
           global val = val * 2
         end
       end
Current value of val = 0.23420933324154358
Current value of val = 0.46841866648308716
Current value of val = 0.9368373329661743
Current value of val = 1.8736746659323487
Current value of val = 3.7473493318646973
Current value of val = 7.494698663729395
Current value of val = 14.98939732745879
Current value of val = 29.97879465491758
Current value of val = 59.95758930983516
Current value of val = 119.91517861967031

julia>
```

See:

- [Global Keyword](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#global)
- [Local Scope](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope-1)
- [Avoid Global Variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables-1)

Comment: That explains why this wasn't happening *inside* any of my functions! Thanks.