# Modify variables inside a for loop within a function

Tags: scope, julia

In the following function

```
function foo(g)
    a = [g * sqrt(i) for i in 1:4]
    b = [g * i ^ 2 for i in 1:4]
    for j in [a, b]
        j /= sum(j)
        println(j)
    end
    
    return a, b
end

foo(2)
```

I expect the printed values to agree with the returned values. Instead, the returned values do not reflect the division performed in line 5. The result is

```
[0.16270045344786252, 0.2300931878702196, 0.2818054517861928, 0.32540090689572504]
[0.03333333333333333, 0.13333333333333333, 0.3, 0.5333333333333333]
([2.0, 2.8284271247461903, 3.4641016151377544, 4.0], [2, 8, 18, 32])
```

I saw a discussion on [the Julia forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-pass-variable-into-loop/25602) where a user was having similar issues in a REPL session. But the suggested solution was to either wrap the for loop in a function, which I have already done, or to write the equivalent of `global j \= sum(j)` in place of line 5, which doesn't change the result.

Similar suggestions appear in this SE question: [Changing variable in loop [Julia]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51909814/changing-variable-in-loop-julia)

How can I batch modify `a` and `b` before returning them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to vectorize the division and use a `Float64` arg:

```
function foo(g)
    a = [g * sqrt(i) for i in 1:4]
    b = [g * i ^ 2 for i in 1:4]
    for j in [a, b]
         j ./= sum(j)
         println(j)
         end
    return a, b
end
```

And now:

```
julia> foo(2.0)
[0.16270045344786252, 0.2300931878702196, 0.2818054517861928, 0.32540090689572504]
[0.03333333333333333, 0.13333333333333333, 0.3, 0.5333333333333333]
([0.16270045344786252, 0.2300931878702196, 0.2818054517861928, 0.32540090689572504], [0.03333333333333333, 0.13333333333333333, 0.3, 0.5333333333333333])
```

Now the tricky explanation

- when you pass an `Int` argument than in your code `a` is a `Vector` of `Float64`s and `b` is a `Vector` of `Int`s. Look what happens when you combine them:

  ```
  julia> [[1.0,2.0],[1,2]]
   2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
   [1.0, 2.0]
   [1.0, 2.0]
  ```

  Julia brings all data to common Float64 and in your case you loose the reference information!
- `j =/ sum(j)` is a linear algebra division and it allocates a new object. You want to have an element wise operation so you needed to vectorize.